# Have Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," - I am trying to return an array where the keys name: and timestamp: are present

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6, push

Have Error : SyntaxError:  Unexpected token, expected "," - I am trying to return an array where the keys name: and timestamp: are present. by pushing into new array where keys are valid
i used, but this gives me back and array where elements are undefined. trying to make new array where these dont exist in new array

```
     const newEvents = events.map(event => (event.name && event.timestamp) && {
        timestamp: event.timestamp,
        name: event.name,
      });
```

//Trying to push into array here when the the keys name: and timestamp: are present.
//But, getting a Unexpected error ","

```
      const newerEvents =[];
      for (const ele of events){
        (ele.name && ele.timestamp) && { newerEvents.push({name: ele.name, timestamp: 
        ele.timestamp}) }
      }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces here are being treated as an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) instead of a "short-circuit" code block:

```
(ele.name && ele.timestamp) && { /* this is an object, not a code block */ }
```

You can fix this by either:

1. Omitting the curly braces `{}`:

   ```
   (ele.name && ele.timestamp) && newerEvents.push({name: ele.name, timestamp: ele.timestamp})
   ```
2. an `if` (for when you need multiple statements):

   ```js
   //populate
   const events = [{timestamp: new Date().getTime(), name: "hi"}];

   const newEvents = events.map(event => (event.name && event.timestamp) && {
           timestamp: event.timestamp,
           name: event.name,
         });
   const newerEvents = [];
   for (const ele of events) {
       if (ele.name && ele.timestamp) {
           newerEvents.push({name: ele.name, timestamp: ele.timestamp});
       }
   }

   //output
   console.log(newerEvents);
   ```

Comment: Thank you, the curly brackets are completely not needed, a jsx reflex.

Comment: Can you get the same functionality in the newerEvents by using an array.map?
currently my attempt in newEvents, using events.map, inserts undefined elements when the two keys are not present.

Comment: @DarkAdvent You can use `filter` beforehand, eg: `myArray.filter(item => item.name && item.timestamp).map(...)`